# Is it ok to use colour character in name (not surname character)?

Tags: names

Is it ok to use colour in mordern Chinese names (I don't mean surname like 黃，白）

For example, there is a name like 叶红鱼，but she seems to be a person from a tale. So I guess is there any mordern names with color in name (not surname).

**UPDATE:** [here is a good guide](https://ninchanese.com/blog/2016/04/07/chinese-names/) about names but there is nothing about colours

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no restriction on the characters in the non-surname part, only good and bad choices. But I'll let others with more experience answer.

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin , here is an example of restriction "But earlier this year [2007] the government announced a ban on names using Arabic numerals, foreign languages and symbols that do not belong to Chinese minority languages." http://edition.cnn.com/2007/funnynews/08/16/strange.name.reut/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I had meant Chinese characters rather than punctuation mark etc. but the prohibition of rare/ancient characters is an important point.

Comment: Totally okay. E.g. a chinese actress 杨紫, where 紫 is purple. 紫 also appears in Chinese male names.

Comment: @STATICOR , would you please leave your answer or comment about my question? I think you should have your opinion about using colour character in given chinese name.

Answer (score 1):

Color character can be used in names. But be careful, a bad combination will ruin everything. I try to make up some.

葉紅 is better than 葉紅魚. It evokes imagination of leaves turning red in the fall.

(It turned out that it's better if the name matches the surname.)

黃 itself is a surname, so I ve heard of few people's names with it.  I propose a name with it, however, for I like it very much.

**懷黃** 黃 means gold seal, a tally of official position. **佩紫懷黃**是也。**懷**, hold. So 懷黃 means hold the gold seal, equivalent of take official position.

（懷 itself is a rare surname）

紫 is always a noble color. The uniforms of high rank officers in many dynasties are of 紫. 有言**事金紫**也。

You may think “佩紫” in “佩紫懷黃” is good （though here 紫 doesn't refer to the color of the uniform）, but it is  phonetically poor to many ears.

**紓紫** has a close meaning as in **綰黃紓紫** and sounds good as well.

Unfortunately 綠 is usually the color of low rank officer's uniforms. But if we give good interpretation, it can also means a lot.

**沈綠**（chen3 lv4）

note：

沈 is not a surname here. For example, 方沈綠 is the full name.

沈 is a variant of 沉, but 沈 looks more poshԅ(¯ㅂ¯ԅ).

Interpretation:

沈綠：dark green. A comfortable, modest color.

Homonymic to 承（cheng3）綠，and 綠 is 籙's original character. So we can interpret it as **承籙**.

**圖籙**，帝王承天命之書也。**承籙** is one of the most ambitious, exaggerate words★.

Then 沈綠 is a superficially modest but actually exaggerate name. And if you explain all things to others you will receive awes for the cultural depth (and pretentiousness (don't care this part, COOL is more important than anything eles!))

There are many other colors, such as 朱/紅/緋/彤/丹/赭/茜/絳/栗/橘/翠/緗/蒼/青/皂/杏/漆/皓/黛/玄/ ……………………

As you may perceive, the examples I give are all about bureaucratic ambition but this is just one of the many topics of a name. So you are totally free of coming up with names of different styles with color characters in.

PS. My most self-content name that I propose is 李 嶔彧 (´▽｀)ノ♪

EDIT:

The poem **紅紅白白花臨水，碧碧黃黃麥際天** suddenly comes to my mind. And I think 際黃（Bordered by wheat fields） is a good choice. （Better with a surname of fourth tone, e.g. 宋際黃）

Comment: 藍/蓝 also appears in many names - due it to being a surname and subsequently a name name.